# 'Alien' ship is discovered but turns out to be from Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Does anyone know a movie where an alien ship is discovered and later on in the movie it turns out the ship is from Earth but they believe it's been buried for thousands of years. They discovered the ship is kind of organic because it is self repairing like a skin. That's all I can remember. Don't even remember if it was TV or movie.

Comment: Possibly Sphere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Is there anything else you can remember about this film - how long ago did you watch it, how old was it, what language was it in, what country was it made in, where/when was it set? Any detail might help someone to find it. You might also like to check out [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Comment: I second the suggestion that it is sphere.

Comment: OK just checked the Sphere, the plot is exactly what I described but is not the movie a saw. the ship wasn't under water and there was no sphere.

Comment: ¿Is there an older version of the Sphere? The one I remember is older, like 80´s; it was in English; made in the US for sure. The Sphere could be, but I will remember such actors as D. Hoffman and S. Stone. being in the one I remember.

Comment: @camilo Can you add to the question that you saw it in the 80s? And also that it wasn't Sphere? All info like that is useful! Anyway, I don't think there was an earlier movie after the same book, since the book came out in 1987.

Comment: Was it in the snow? Does it involve aliens that look just like us?

Comment: @camilo the novel Sphere came out in 1987; the movie version with Hoffman in it came out in 1998.

Answer (score 5):

## [The Outer Limits (1995 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series))

**"Double Helix" (episode 3x12; 1997)** is about a professor in the 20th Century who activates a dormant part of his genetic code which leads him and a group of young adults to a spaceship that has been buried for 60 million years.  The ship, though not self-repairing, is so durable that it has not taken damage in all its time underground, and the military are unable to remove hull samples to test.  The professor's genetic modification gives him access to the ship's interior, and he and the young adults board.  The ship then departs Earth.

The story continues in **"The Origin of Species" (episode 4x19; 1998)**.  The ship lands on a planet that turns out to be Earth of the future — sometime after the mid-23rd Century — on which humanity went extinct due to side-effects of genetic engineering.  The ship reveals to its passengers from the 20th Century that it was created by an ancient Earth civilization that experienced a similar genetically-engineered accidental extinction.  These ancients created the ship to assist any future civilization in overcoming this kind of disaster, and seeded Earth life with the genetic code needed to find and operate this technology.  During the voyage from the 20th Century, the ship used its human passengers as templates to create babies to help humanity repopulate Earth.

You mentioned thinking that the show you saw was from the 1980s.  These episodes of *The Outer Limits* were made more recently, in the 1990s, but the production timeline is close to what you remember.

You can watch ["Double Helix"](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5ved19) and ["The Origin of Species"](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x61lcqy) online.  **Warning:** On these pages, some of the thumbnail images linking to other videos are explicit and NSFW (not safe for work).